# Good SMTP server on Windows for a production server

Tags: windows, smtp

I'm going to have my website hosted soon on a VPS or dedicated server (with Windows 2008), so I'm trying to plan ahead. I wonder whether the built-in SMTP server that comes with IIS7 is reliable enough for a production server or should I look for an alternative? I heard good things about hmailserver and best of all it's free, do you have any experience with using the bulit-in SMTP on a high traffic website.

Thanks a lot for any suggestions

Answer (score 9):

I hit this thread via Google but I was looking for an outbound only SMTP server for transactional emails (customer registration confirmation etc. but not marketing), then some things I discovered are:

SMTP does still exist in Windows Server 2008.

Server Manager > Features (not Roles) > Right-click, Add > SMTP Server - then Configure IIS 7 SMTP to point to the local server.

Then use the Framework to do the business: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Jango have a paid for but cheap enough service for exactly this kind of thing. The Free account only allows 200/month but might be useful for some folk.

http://www.jangosmtp.com/Pricing.asp

Good luck!

**UPDATE**

I blogged about setting up the original MS SMTP Server on Windows Server 2008.

http://www.lukepuplett.com/2010/06/how-to-send-email-from-microsoft-server.html

Comment: Not direct answers to the OP's questions, but lots of useful info in a thread that ranks high on Google when searching for "open source smtp windows", so upvoted. Thanks for sharing your info!

Comment: You're welcome - I hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 4):

[hMailServer](https://www.hmailserver.com/).  Free and open source.

Comment: Nice one, but it cannot manage multiple IPs / hostnames.

Answer (score 3):

At work, we used to use the SMTP server in IIS 6.0 for years and it was perfectly fine.

Eventually, we just simply didn't want all the issues that come with running your SMTP server so we mapped our MX records to a third-party service and moved on with our lives.

It's not actually that bad an idea to map your MX records to a third-party provider, like Google. It's one service less to configure and one service less to patch.

Answer (score 2):

What about **[xmailserver](http://www.xmailserver.org/)** (as suggested in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076/need-a-lightweight-free-windows-smtp-server)) ?

It is free, and for Windows or linux (should you migrate on a linux server platform)

[image]
<sub>(source: [xmailserver.org](http://www.xmailserver.org/logoxmail.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This is an old post but I thought I'd make a recommendation since this does seem to come up frequently.

In my opinion you should try to avoid running mail on your `VPS/Dedicated` Server if you can. It's one more thing to manage and one more headache.  My recommendation would be that use a 3rd party service like sendgrid.com that will allow you to relay mail through them.  This way you won't have to worry about your new server getting blacklisted or being seen as having a low reputation score and your messages not making it out of the user's spam box.  The other issue is that when you setup your mail server, you need to secure it and you need to make sure it's got a reverse DNS entries, many providers won't provide that and/or they'll recycle IP addresses so that the IP address of your server actually has a poor reputation.

Comment: 1) You have to trust this provider. 2) You will pay additional money. Nice attempt but NO!

Answer (score 1):

Being on windows, your best choice will probably be IIS.

If it was Linux, I'd suggest postfix.

Answer (score 1):

you haven't mentioned if you are needing to receive mail, or just to send it.
One of the best all around solutions for a windows mail server is IpSwitch's iMail (http://www.ipswitch.com/), but it costs.

If you mainly need to send mail, then your best bet is to use an upstream smtp server.

IIS smtp services are, in general, not useful.  If you use Exchange, it gets a bit better, but still not very efficient, and not the most secure by any means.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe sending it via gmail is a good one :P
Ok serious. <strike>IIS7 seems I heard to have some decent improvement.</strike> If that's not doing it, I guess you could try free stuff like mailenable.
(No I can't find the evidence on the improvement on IIS SMTP, people who know about this please comment)

Long term you might end up split it to a linux based smtp though, that gives you some flexibility on server farming if it goes too insane.

And if its for any kind of mass mailing that might trigger spam server blocking, don't ever try to host it together with your other important stuff- you want to keep yourself have a back step if your server gets blocked.